# Mount Docker volume on Windows host with Linux containers in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just started using Docker and the Docker Compose feature to set up my Web App services. I'm running Docker on a Windows Host using Linux Containers. I got this named volume called db_volume that I use for my PostgreSQL service.

```
services:
  postgres_image:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "db1"
volumes:
  db_volume:
```

When I use `docker volume inspect` on this named volume, I can see that the Mountpoint path is a Linux path.

```
"Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/dockercompose18019271739475279775_db_volume/_data"
```

I was wondering if there is any way to convert this path to a Windows one so that I can import these data in my pgadmin databases.

I already set the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` in my .env file, but it didn't seem to work.

I also shared both my `C` and `D` drive in the Docker settings.

Comment: Another option is to just copy your files directly into the volume with `docker cp`. You can copy from a host path to a container path or container to container. To name your container for easy usage add the option `container_name: my_postgres` in docker-compose.yml. Here's that copy with a single command: (first put your files in your selected Windows folder, let's say d:/pgdata) then just run `docker cp d:/pgdata/ my_posgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data`. That way you are decoupled from Win/Lin host.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to convert this to a windows path, because in this scenario it is not on the windows filesystem. The storage you have allocated is on the MobyLinux VM which is created as part of your windows install. If you want to have the storage appear as part of your local windows filesystem then you need to do something like this which maps the data directory to the host filesystem:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: pg
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - d:/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "db1"
```

You should note that on windows you will need expose your drive via the "Shared Drives" settings in the Docker settings.

Comment: When I change the `volumes` path to the `d:/pgdata` directory, I get a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'No route to host'`

Comment: Do you actually have a local directory on your windows machine called ```d:\pgdata``` ?

Comment: Yes, I created one

Answer (score 0):

you'll need something like this:

```
volumes: 
      - //d/pgdata/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

for Windows filesystem and from c# you'll request
"/var/lib/postgresql/data" path