# WSL2: Access container build result from host: `docker cp` vs. bind mount

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I am using Docker with WSL2 to build a project and would like to access the build results of the container from the host.

It appears there are two ways for accessing the build results:

- Use `docker cp`
- Use bind mount

With WSL2 there is a performance decrease when bind mounting the Windows file system (opposed to the WSL2 `\\wsl$` Linux file system), see [Docker Desktop - Filesharing notification about poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64484579) and [WSL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#performance-across-os-file-systems). However, I would like to avoid using `\\wsl$`  since I would then have to make sure to pick a unique path there for storing the build results, copying them to the current directory and then properly cleaning the `\\wsl$` dir up again (unless I am misunderstand something here?).

This leaves me with the following two options:

- Use `docker cp`
  This requires three Docker commands:

  1. Build the artifact
     `docker container run ...`
  2. Copy the artifact to the host
     `docker cp ...`
  3. Remove container
     `docker container rm ...`
- Use bind mount

  1. Build the artifact in a non-mounted directory (for performance, see above)
  2. Copy the artifact to the mounted directory

My question is now: Which of these options is more efficient? Or are there any other efficient and simple alternatives?

I would assume `docker cp ...` *could* be more efficient since it might be able to access the container data without the performance penalty a bind mount would have; however the three separate Docker commands deter me a bit since if any of these fails (for whatever reason) I manually have to copy the artifact or clean up the container.